# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 38"

Tags: java

For an assignment I have almost ready but can't seem to get past the error .. 
the file items.txt data

> 12345,Ballpeen Hammer,25,18.75
>
> 56789,Phillips Screwdriver,120,10.95
>
> 24680,Claw Hammer,35,15.98
>
> 13579,Box Wrench,48,20.35
>
> 28967,Hex Wrench,70,19.98

the file activity.txt data

> D,12345,0
>
> R,12345,100
>
> S,12345,45

The error i am getting again and again it tells me the error

```
                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 38"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at InventoryItemTest.main(InventoryItemTest.java:21)
```

C:\Users\Noah\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

The code that is not working

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Scanner;

     public class InventoryItemTest {
     private static final int INVENTORY_SIZE=100;
     public static void main(String[] args)
            {
               InventoryItem[] inventoryItems= new 
               InventoryItem[INVENTORY_SIZE];
                        int i= 0;
                 //Process the file
                 try {
                                                                                          Scanner scanfile = new Scanner(new File("items.txt"));

        while (scanfile.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] lines = scanfile.nextLine().split(",");
            if(Integer.parseInt(lines[0])>=20000 && Integer.parseInt(lines[0])<=79999) { 
                inventoryItems[i] = new InventoryItem(Integer.parseInt(lines[0]), lines[1], Integer.parseInt(lines[2]), Double.parseDouble(lines[3]));
                i++;
           }
        }
        System.out.println(i+" items has been created.");
        scanfile.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.err.println("FILE NOT FOUND!!!!");
    }

    try
    {
        int processedCount=0,skippedCount=0;
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File("activity.txt"));

        while (scanFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            String[] tokens = scanFile.nextLine().split(",");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            System.out.println(id);
            int q = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            for (int j = 0; j <i ; j++) {
                if(id==inventoryItems[j].getItemNumber())
                {
                    processedCount++;
                    switch (tokens[0])
                    {
                        case "D":
                            inventoryItems[j].setQuantity(q);
                            break;
                        case "R":
                            inventoryItems[j].receiveItems(q);
                            break;
                        case "S":
                            inventoryItems[j].shipItems(q);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                skippedCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Number of received Process: "+processedCount);
        System.out.println("Number of records skipped: "+skippedCount);
        scanFile.close();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("report.txt"));
        //Preparing Report
        double grandTotal=0;
        double value =0;

        writer.println("Joe E. Bagadonuts for the Albatross Company, Ltd.\nPrepared On: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        writer.println("\t\tI N V E N T O R Y  R E P O R T\nInventory Item");
        writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %10s %10s","Number","Description","Quantity","Unit Price","Value"));
        writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %10s %10s","------","-----------","--------","----------","------"));
        for (int j = 0; j <i ; j++) {
            value = inventoryItems[j].getQuantity()*inventoryItems[j].getUnitCost();
            grandTotal+=value;
            writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %11s %11s",inventoryItems[j].getItemNumber(),inventoryItems[j].getDescription(),inventoryItems[j].getQuantity(),NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(inventoryItems[j].getUnitCost()),NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(value)));

        }
        writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %10s %10s"," "," "," ","","==================="));
        writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %11s %11s"," "," "," ","Total ", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(grandTotal)));

        writer.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.err.println("File not found...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error in creating report");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it looks like your String has a space in it. call trim() before calling `parseInt`

Comment: which string were you looking at sir?

Comment: @JohnRyder the " 38" your error message is talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that exception because the number that you are trying to parse has space with it. `trim()` is a function in java which is used to remove space before and after a string. Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-trim-method-example/) to know more about trim.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InventoryItemTest {
    private static final int INVENTORY_SIZE=100;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InventoryItem[] inventoryItems= new
                InventoryItem[INVENTORY_SIZE];
        int i= 0;
        //Process the file
        try {
            Scanner scanfile = new Scanner(new File("items.txt"));

            while (scanfile.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] lines = scanfile.nextLine().split(",");
                int i1 = Integer.parseInt(lines[0].trim());
                if(i1>=20000 && i1<=79999) {
                    inventoryItems[i] = new InventoryItem(i1, lines[1], Integer.parseInt(lines[2].trim()), Double.parseDouble(lines[3].trim()));
                    i++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(i+" items has been created.");
            scanfile.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("FILE NOT FOUND!!!!");
        }

        try
        {
            int processedCount=0,skippedCount=0;
            Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File("activity.txt"));

            while (scanFile.hasNextLine())
            {
                String[] tokens = scanFile.nextLine().split(",");
                int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim());
                System.out.println(id);
                int q = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].trim());
                for (int j = 0; j <i ; j++) {
                    if(id==inventoryItems[j].getItemNumber())
                    {
                        processedCount++;
                        switch (tokens[0])
                        {
                            case "D":
                                inventoryItems[j].setQuantity(q);
                                break;
                            case "R":
                                inventoryItems[j].receiveItems(q);
                                break;
                            case "S":
                                inventoryItems[j].shipItems(q);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    skippedCount++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Total Number of received Process: "+processedCount);
            System.out.println("Number of records skipped: "+skippedCount);
            scanFile.close();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("report.txt"));
            //Preparing Report
            double grandTotal=0;
            double value =0;

            writer.println("Joe E. Bagadonuts for the Albatross Company, Ltd.\nPrepared On: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            writer.println("\t\tI N V E N T O R Y  R E P O R T\nInventory Item");
            writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %10s %10s","Number","Description","Quantity","Unit Price","Value"));
            writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %10s %10s","------","-----------","--------","----------","------"));
            for (int j = 0; j <i ; j++) {
                value = inventoryItems[j].getQuantity()*inventoryItems[j].getUnitCost();
                grandTotal+=value;
                writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %11s %11s",inventoryItems[j].getItemNumber(),inventoryItems[j].getDescription(),inventoryItems[j].getQuantity(),NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(inventoryItems[j].getUnitCost()),NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(value)));

            }
            writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %10s %10s"," "," "," ","","==================="));
            writer.println(String.format("%5s %19s %10s %11s %11s"," "," "," ","Total ", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(grandTotal)));

            writer.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("File not found...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error in creating report");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes this works, I'm really thankful for your help i cant express how much stress im saved from thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try using below method while calling parseInt in InventoryItemTest while reading items.txt.

```
Integer getIntVal(String val){
 return val!=null ? Integer.parseInt(val.trim()) : null;
}
```

Eg:

```
if(getIntVal(lines[0])>=20000 && getIntVal(lines[0])<=79999) { 
                inventoryItems[i] = new InventoryItem(getIntVal(lines[0]), lines[1], getIntVal(lines[2]), Double.parseDouble(lines[3]));
                i++;
           }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use trim() wherever you are accessing your lines[] array.

```
 if (Integer.parseInt(lines[0].trim().trim()) >= 20000 && Integer.parseInt(lines[0].trim()) <= 79999)
 {
      inventoryItems[i] = new InventoryItem(Integer.parseInt(lines[0].trim()), lines[1].trim(), Integer.parseInt(lines[2].trim()), Double.parseDouble(lines[3].trim()));
      i++;
 }
```

Comment: tysm :heart: I appreciate ur help